# Overlap 2 RGBA images using Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a image segmentation project.

I have 2 RGBA images.
First image is the image to segment:

[image]

The second is an image which contains red squares with different transparency value:

[image]

I would like to superimpose the 2 images, but I can't do it. I tried 2 methods :

One by using openCV "add" method and the other by using PIL "blend" method.

```
from PIL import Image as PImage

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    image_A = read_image(r"C:\Users\francois.bock\Desktop\013.jpg", rgb=True)

    # Add alpha channel
    image_A = np.concatenate((image_A, np.full((256, 256, 1), fill_value=255, dtype=np.uint8)), axis=2)

    #Create image B
    image_B = np.full((256, 256, 4), fill_value=[0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(0, 20):
        for j in range(0, 20):
            image_B[i, j] = [255, 0, 0, 100]

    for i in range(50, 70):
        for j in range(50, 70):
            image_B[i, j] = [255, 0, 0, 127]

    for i in range(50, 70):
        for j in range(0, 20):
            image_B[i, j] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

    image_A_convert = PImage.fromarray(image_A)
    image_B_convert = PImage.fromarray(image_B)

    # Test with blend
    img_add = PImage.blend(image_A_convert, image_B_convert, 0.0)
    img_add.save("testrgba.png", "PNG")

    # Test with open CV
    img_add = cv2.add(image_A,image_B)
    img_add = PImage.fromarray(img_add)
    img_add.save("testrgba.png", "PNG")
```

Result with blend:

[image]

Result with open CV

[image]

As we can see it doesn't work well.

With blend method, the first image got too fade.
With openCV method, the first image is OK but we lost transparency specific to each square of the second image.

I would like to keep the same first image, but with transparency specific to each square of the second image.

Any tips or hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a simple `paste()` with mask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open input images, background and overlay
image   = Image.open('bg.png')
overlay = Image.open('overlay.png')

# Paste overlay onto background using overlay alpha as mask
image.paste(overlay, mask=overlay)

# Save
image.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know this method. It works perfectly. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add some weight to it in form of `g(x) = (1-a)f0(x) + af1(x)`.

Assign a variable

`beta = (1.0 - alpha)` 
and

`dst = cv.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0)`.

Then

`dst = np.uint8(alpha*(img1)+beta*(img2))`

`cv.imshow('dst', dst)`

where `src1 is Image1 and src2 is Image2`. Try with different value of `alpha`. For me `alpha = 0.5` worked fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Btw, It is using OpenCV